# Mapping List not getting all items from master list

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I am exporting 32 thousand products but there is a strange probelm the retList is only getting 1917 items I have no idea why that is the case.

```
 private List<FTradeItemsExport> MapTradeItems(List<TradeItems> tradeItem)
    {
        List<TradeItemsExport> retList = new List<TradeItemsExport>();
        try
            {

                var StockImport = new Fuel_StockItemImports();


                List<StandardLookUpList> _AnalsisCodes = GetAnayalsisCodesForExportCode();

                StandardLookUpList sport = new StandardLookUpList();
                StandardLookUpList gender = new StandardLookUpList();
                StandardLookUpList colour = new StandardLookUpList();
                StandardLookUpList Size = new StandardLookUpList();
                StandardLookUpList categorycode = new StandardLookUpList();
                StandardLookUpList categorydesc = new StandardLookUpList();
                StandardLookUpList subcategorycode = new StandardLookUpList();
                StandardLookUpList subcategorydesc = new StandardLookUpList();

                StandardLookUpList brandcode = new StandardLookUpList();
                StandardLookUpList branddesc = new StandardLookUpList();


                foreach (var item in tradeItem)
                {

                    var codesForThisItem = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode);
                    if (codesForThisItem.Any())
                    {
                        sport = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Sport);

                        gender = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Gender);
                        colour = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Colour);
                        Size = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Size);
                        categorycode = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Colour);
                        categorydesc = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Category);

                        subcategorycode = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Category);
                        subcategorydesc = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.SubCategory);
                        brandcode = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Brand);
                    }
                    retList.Add(new  TradeItemsExport()
                    {
                        ItemCode = item.ItemCode,
                        BarCode = item.BarCode,
                        Description = item.Description,
                        SupplierCode = item.SupplierCode,
                        SupplierStockCode = item.SupplierStockCode,
                        Product_Group_Code = "",
                        Product_Group_Desc = "",
                        SportCode = sport.LookupValue.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        SportDesc = sport.description.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        GenderCode = gender.LookupValue.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        GenderDesc = gender.description.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        ColourCode = colour.LookupValue.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        ColourDesc = colour.description.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        SizeCode = Size.LookupValue.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        SizeDesc = Size.description.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        CategoryCode = categorycode.LookupValue.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        CategoryDesc = categorydesc.description.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        subcategorycode = subcategorycode.LookupValue.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        subcategorydesc = subcategorydesc.description.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        BrandsCode = brandcode.LookupValue.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        BrandsDesc = branddesc.description.ToStringOrEmpty(),
                        Vat = item.Vat,
                        GrossWeight = item.Weight,
                        CommodityCode = item.CommodityCode,
                        price_exVAT = item.price_exVAT,
                        price_incVAT = item.price_incVAT,
                        currentprice_exVAT = item.currentprice_exVAT,
                        currentprice_incVAT = item.currentprice_incVAT,
                        creation_date = item.creation_date,
                        Inactive_date = item.Inactive_date,
                        status = 1



                    });
                    var Stock = new Fuel_StockItemImport();



                    Stock.StockItem = item.ItemCode;
                    Stock.IsProcessed = true;
                    Stock.DateImported = DateTime.Now;
                    StockImport.Add(Stock);
                    StockImport.Update();


                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return retList;


    }
```

As you can see the below is the true figure of items expected in the mapping list I dont understand as I am not getting any exceptions on the data?. While I step through the code and check my brake points its not bombing out anywhere with null reference so not to sure what is going on.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Seemd like a bad solution to hold 32 000 objects in memory

Comment: I need to be able to export the items to csv so what is my alternative

Comment: You can stream write data into a file

Comment: If you provide an example would be good but i still need to transform that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that this could happen is that you ignore an exception in the middle of the loop after inserting precisely 1912 items.

Most likely reason for it are calls to `ToStringOrEmpty()` when constructing `TradeItemsExport` objects. You can fix this by using `?.` operator.

In general, you should not ignore all exceptions with `catch (Exception ex) { }` that does nothing. If you do not know what to do with an exception, you shouldn't have code that catches it. In this case it's clearly a programming problem (failure to null-check your objects) so `try` / `catch` should be removed altogether.

> *(from the comments)* Is there a faster way of merging them?

You can improve the speed considerably by replacing `Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode)` with a hash-based lookup in a dictionary:

```
var byItemCode = _AnalsisCodes
    .GroupBy(w => w.ItemCode)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First());
...
foreach (var item in tradeItem) {
    if (byItemCode.TryGetValue(item.ItemCode, out var codesForThisItem) && codesForThisItem.Any()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If this does not speed things up by enough margin, you would need to re-organize the lookups inside `codesForThisItem` by setting up dictionaries before going into the loop.

Comment: Is there a faster way of merging them it seems really slow and you where right there was another error deaper down but it still seems way to slow